Are comments obsolete in favor of Generative AI?
With generative AI, you can just ask it to explain the code to you.  In my experience, it is reliable and accurate - which cannot always be said about manual comments.  I am specifically referring to comments on signatures - not necessarily inline comments, TODOs, or things of that nature.
It would save time (I think) by not writing and maintaining comments.  A good generative AI for code isn't always free, but I suspect it will become built into IDEs sooner rather than later.  Without comments on signatures, there is no IntelliSense/preview when you hover a function, but I suspect that will be added to IDEs soon.
My question:
I make an effort to always comment the signature of anything public or unintuitive.  But I am now considering stopping comments (except for exceptional cases).  Is this a bad idea?
An example:
public bool IsEven(int number)
{
    return number % 2 == 0;
}

My comments:
/// <summary>
/// Checks whether the number is even
/// </summary>
/// <param name="number">The number to check</param>
/// <returns>Whether the number is even</returns>

Generative AI (JetBrains) comments:


Your comment in this example is not obsolete because you found an AI which can explain this method. Your comment was obsolete right from the start, because the function signature is self-explanatory. Try an AI with a non-trivial function in the middle of a large program, one which calls several other non-trivial function written by you or another team, where the funcion names are that self-explanatory (at least not without knowing the context).

A big problem with this idea is that you’d be approximating having someone who didn’t write the code comment it after the fact. That’s not ideal in the best case because they’d have to guess at intent. If there are bugs (I didn’t implement exactly what I intended), the retroactive commenter is likely to give the wrong description. All the more when the commenter is AI not a human, since humans reason with logic; LLMs parrot human language with zero understanding.

"In my experience..." Which makes it essential that you tell us what your experience is.  How many years, in what field, on what kinds of projects?  This genuinely isn't to say "oh, we've been doing this longer, so you can't be right".  If you're correct then that's great - but my experience is that that I can't see it working well for anything I've been involved with (various C and C++ embedded software over 30 years).

Have you tried it with a less trivial example? Can it actually comment anything substantial?

I trust generative AI to provide an accurate summary even less than I trust a programmer to keep comments up-to-date.

You should look up the amount of power LLMs use. Like, it seems like such an waste to generate compared to comments

"With generative AI, you can just ask it to explain the code to you"
And it will explain to me what the code does. Which I already know, because I can see the code myself with my own eyes. What I need comments to do is tell me things I need to know, that cannot be ascertained simply by reading the code; generative AI cannot do this any more than I can.

The claim that you know what the code does, because you can see it is a bit naive. Especially when some sophisticated math or algorithms are involved.

hmm... it can if someone else wrote similar code, with the good comments you want and put it on github

@Mochops you may be correct in OPs case, but tools like Github Copilot are context aware and take into account usage of the method in question and other similar methods and are capable of generalizations. So if the code had tests, the method description would likely be more usage oriented and would have less implementation details.

Ewan: In this code, replace number % 2 == 0 with number % 3 == 1. From a well known pattern to something that is easy enough, but quite obscure. I’d be curious what the AI generated comments would be.

@gnasher729 "This function is checking if a number is divisible by 3, not if it's even. The correct function to check if a number is even would be:"

A great practical example of something you don't see with your own two eyes is an approximation for another function.  The other function simply isn't in the code, so AI can't see it.  The best one can do with AI in that case is hope that that particular approximation is extremely common and that other human beings commented their code so it could copy the comments for you.

@freakish but if the code can't be understood that easily, what're the odds that an AI is going to explain it properly? And how will you be sure that it is?

@freakish You are kind of making Moschops’s point for him. Anyone can read code. What it means is non-obvious for both humans and AI.

I cant tell if the people arguing for gen AI to explain code blocks actually code. Comments are for the why, and the contextual. Abstraction and modularity squelch complexity, not ChatGPT. Any software engineer of moderate expertise can read a code block. Sure some code may take longer, but then they could simply refactor it to something simpler anyway.

@Dúthomhas what I'm really saying is that AI can still understand and describe code even if human can't. Things not obvious to human, aren't necessarily not obvious to AI.

@Erik literally all static analysis tools exist exactly to explain and catch coding errors that humans are incapable of catching themselves. I think the chances that humans are bad at programming are insanely high. So even non-AI software already does great job at it, so I'm not sure where your argument comes from.

And of course we would believe what AI tells us. Just like we believe that whatever machine code a compiler generates is fine. Let's be honest: pretty much noone reads the output.

@freakish there's a difference between static code analysis (which is built to know and very specific in what it does) and AI language models (which are built to generate reasonable sounding BS, and generally have no relation to reality unless the case is really trivial). If you "believe what AI tells you" in the current era, you should really apply more critical thinking, because any semblance of truth is more accidental than intentional.

@Erik the only difference is that AI is capable of more than what static analysis tool is capable of. Also, AI is in no less relation to reality than human are. I don't believe AI more or less then any human. That's the real critical thinking. You overestimate human, and their insane capability of lying (or simply being wrong) by huge margin. In fact 99% of developers are incapable of doing any programming with assistance of tools. Why would you believe their work? Just because they are people? Good luck with that.

@freakish When you say AI, I assume you're referring to LLM's like ChatGPT? These models don't and can't understand code.

@freakish Your assertion that "AI is capable of more than what static analysis tool is capable of" is very much wrong. A static analysis tool is completely incapable of doing what an AI does, and an AI is completely incapable of doing what a static analysis tool does. Yes, we humans make mistakes pretty frequently, but we can check ourselves and each other and fix the mistakes. You can't use AI to fix mistakes autonomously, because it'll introduce new mistakes faster than it'll fix the existing ones.

@freakish "AI can still understand and describe code even if human can't." – Sure, in the same sense that a stopped clock can still show the correct time even when a running clock can't. I once asked ChatGPT 4 to prove that for all numbers x and y, x * y + x = x * y + 1. It wrote pages and pages of garbage, completely failing to notice the very obvious fact that the statement isn't actually true. If you call that "understanding," I would say that you have a very interesting idea of what the word "understanding" means.

@Moschops This answer assumes a LOT: That the users is as competent with the language as the AI. That the user is as familiar with the code as the AI. That the user is as familiar with the patterns used as the AI.  if ANY of these are false, I don't think the answer holds for the given user.

@tuskiomi The answer is that I need the comments to tell me things that cannot be ascertained by reading the code. That holds.

@TannerSwett of course AI can do anything that any other tool can: simply by running it. And yes, the tech for that already exists, it's just that people don't want it to do that. And of course AI can fix any mistake as long as it is informed that it is a mistake. Through whatever channel, doesn't even have to be another human. Btw, your example of "prove that" is flawed on so many levels, starting from the fact that whether it is true or not depends on context (i.e. you did not define those symbols).

@freakish "of course AI can do anything that any other tool can: simply by running it." – Indeed, but only if the AI actually manages to invoke the tool correctly and usefully. In my experience, ChatGPT very often gives the wrong answer because, although a particular tool is available and needed for the problem, ChatGPT fails to attempt to use it. "And of course AI can fix any mistake as long as it is informed that it is a mistake." – Yes, but finding the mistake is usually the hard part. "whether it is true or not depends on context (i.e. you did not define those symbols)." – Incorrect.

@TannerSwett of course it is context dependent. I'm a mathematician. Your equation is totally correct over say trivial ring. And many many other structures.

@freakish That's fair. I felt that it was unnecessary to write "under the standard mathematical meanings of the terms used" (in particular, given a standard meaning of the word "numbers"—the statement is false whether that's taken to mean "natural numbers," "integers," "real numbers," or "complex numbers").

@TannerSwett either way, AI is not capable of creating proofs. Not now anyway. But humans are very bad at it as well, considering that entire science is created by a percent of a percent of people. I assure you that 99% of people is incapable of even understanding mathematical problems. Secondly chatGPT is a plaything for kids really.

@Moschops if you've  ever had to read code more than once to understand it, you've answered your own question. If you've never had to do this, you can visit https://leetcode.com/ and go to the solutions section to the questions to find out more

"And it will explain to me what the code does." If you're lucky.

@tuskomi Answered my own question? I don't have any questions here. I have an answer. My answer is that I need comments to tell me what I need to know that cannot be ascertained by reading the code.

@Ewan: Your suggested comment is first of all totally wrong. My function didn’t check whether a number is divisible by 3. It didn’t tell how it would indicate this. And then it jumped off on a tangent making a stupid guess that the intent of this function is something completeLy different from what it says.

@gnasher729 i think i was quoting an AI response. to your previous comment. I cant really remember

Three things:

If AI could sufficiently document code, it should be done once at the time the code is authored, not many times every time someone forgets what the code does. This is primarily an efficiency concern. But, it also allows the author an opportunity to validate or edit the comment to align with their own understanding.
The explanation generated in your example is harder to read than the actual code. But, this is often the nature of LLM's: They do with many words what you can often do better with few (or none).
The best comments don't usually need to explain "what" code does, but "why" it is as it is. E.g., look at this:

constructor() {
  this._graphqlParse = someLib.parse;
}

It looks benign enough. We're just using the parse method from "someLib". What if we want to swap that out later? Is it OK to do that? If I don't have some in depth knowledge of "someLib", I have no reason to think I shouldn't swap it out with another library.
But, what if it had this comment on it?
constructor() {
  // someLib's parse method safely escapes template literal params for us
  // so we don't have to worry about injection attacks.
  this._graphqlParse = someLib.parse;
}

How I think about that tiny little assignment and library dependency is now completely different. I now know that if I go hunting for a faster library or a library that emits metrics or whatever, I need to find one that also sanitizes strings.
In the original, undocumented code, "what" the code does is obvious. "Why" I've done it the way I've done it was not. The "why" matters. And an LLM can only "guess" (same as you1) at the original author's intentions.

1. An LLM doesn't really guess like a human does. It's basically a giant statistical auto-completion engine. But, I think you know what I mean here. The LLM doesn't know anything about the author's intentions or decision making process.

"an LLM can only guess" – I know what you mean, but I feel this statement is misleading and feeds into the widespread misunderstanding about what LLMs can and cannot do. An LLM is essentially spicy autocomplete. It doesn't understand anything, it has no intelligence, and it also can't "guess". Unless someone has already written this same code with a well-written comment, and that code was part of the training set of the LLM, there is practically no chance an LLM will be able to generate a coherent comment.

Hmm ... I'm a little skeptical that this is "misleading", TBH. But, I'll add a footnote. You can let me know if you think it's helpful.

Except the AI will do a much poorer job at guessing than the collective you. Never trust AI to author whatever an expert can’t or won’t thoroughly review, comments included.

Regarding 1) you might want to argue why. Aside from money/resources spent, I'd also see the fact that you cannot predict what an AI used by someone else will spit out when they ask for documentation/a summary. Feel free to incorporate if you agree.

@FrankHopkins I took a crack at a revision.

Note, that LLM could read JiRA and commit comments just as well as code author, and may be even scan blame history. So this answer is pro-AI.

@Basilevs Sure... assuming the author left evidence of their decision process in JIRA, and assuming the LLM connects that thread with that line of code... Ok. Remember that this is just an example as well. Even if your team is leaving tons of notes, many of the little decisions you make during implementation are on-the-fly. It's also a like ironic that you're suggesting it's "pro-AI" because the AI can find other places where I the author has already written the comment, basically... Sure. That's not a bad use case. Use AI to search for relevant decisions and suggest comments to the author

@Basilevs this isn't really a pro vs. con AI discussion but a specific does this particular process (writing comments) become obsolete by this particular approach to use AI; That being said, you argue in your comments mostly that if the project is that well maintained that the AI can get to the bottom of everything then the AI will be generating a good enough output - which begs the question why you still need the AI to put out anything, if the project already has all the right information in the right places... (and for the detailed "why"s jira tickets wouldn't be the right place)

And, I still argue for point 1 then. If the LLM can produce the correct comments, the original author is best suited to validate those comments and commit those comments

@FrankHopkins so that an author would not have to write them (at most review and find flaws).

@JörgWMittag To claim that LLMs have no understanding and no intelligence, you first have to define both of those terms and then prove that humans have it and LLMs don't. You could instead say that "LLMs have poor reasoning abilities and are very unreliable", which is just as useful but doesn't require making extraordinary claims.

+1 for mentioning the /most/ important question in Computing - "Why?"

@TheGuywithTheHat, that is not true. LLM’s are architecturally incapable of intelligence and understanding; their output is based strictly on statistics to estimate the best-fitting next word in a sentence. There is no need to define the terms to know when it cannot be present.

@JamesMcLeod Huh? How can you know that a thing can't be present if you don't even know what the thing is? I have yet to see a definition of "intelligence" or "understanding" that fits humans, doesn't fit LLMs, and isn't contrived specifically to separate the two.

As much as I'd love to dig into the philosophy of sentience, let's not do it in the comments here, please.

That function is a great example of why not all functions need comments. Comments (and  function docs) are to explain things that aren't immediately obvious. For example this (pretend) hand written documentation is useful:
/**
* Determines if invoices for this product requires the 
* <a href="http://mycompany.confluence.com/wingbat">wingbat</a> 
* payment pre processor. If not it can be sent RAW to accounts
*/
public boolean needsWingbatPreProcessor(ProductIdentifier productIdentifier) {
     // hats come from ACME hat and their payment provider can't handle raw invoices
     if(productIdentifier.hasHatIncluded()){
         return true; 
     }
     // turns out that BOT products have an undocumented bug that requires the preprocessor, See JIRA-89
     if(productIdentifier.getIdentifier().startsWith("BOT-"){
         return true; 
     }
     return false.
} 

For reference I gave an AI my example method and asked it to add javadocs and comments. This is what I got back:
/**
 * Determines if a wingbat pre-processor is needed based on the product identifier.
 * A wingbat pre-processor is needed if:
 * - The product identifier indicates a hat is included.
 * - The product identifier starts with "BOT-".
 *
 * @param productIdentifier The product identifier to check.
 * @return {@code true} if a wingbat pre-processor is needed, {@code false} otherwise.
 */
public boolean needsWingbatPreProcessor(ProductIdentifier productIdentifier) {
    // Check if the product identifier indicates a hat is included
    if (productIdentifier.hasHatIncluded()) {
        return true;
    }

    // Check if the product identifier starts with "BOT-"
    if (productIdentifier.getIdentifier().startsWith("BOT-")) {
        return true;
    }

    // If neither condition is met, return false
    return false;
}

The hand written docs are clearly more useful, giving a link to an article on what wingbat is (Which I'm pretending is an internal tool). And explaining the weird cases in this function. On the other hand the AI one just describes what it does

The AI also forgot to mention the JIRA ticket

Thus is is not a fair comparison. For the task to be done correctly, AI has to have access ro the task statement, Git history and the workspace.

@Basilevs how is that not a fair comparison. Until we have much better AI trained on local data (which is very very expensive) that is what an AI can do. Sure some day better AIs may be available.  But even in that case the AI that wrote the code should add the comment explaining why it did what it did. Not have another AI guessing at it. The point is that comments are "I was there, I saw what happened, here is what I saw". Docs and comments written after the fact (either by a human or by AI) are usually much less useful

@rRichardTingle that's exactly the point - for example, Github Copilot, that has access to original task and workspace would have done much better job. Just do not use AI not designed for what you are trying to do.

@Basilevs but why would an AI (even a really good AI) do a better job that the original author (human or AI). Humans are already general intelligences and don't do a good job adding retrospective documentation (but do add good documentation when writing it at the time). Why do you think an AI (a weaker intelligence than a human) would do a better job writing retrospective comments guessing at why something was done

I was talking about original documentation - Copilot does not have access to history (unfortunately). So you give it task description in a chat, it spits out some code, you work together to polish it. In particular you might ask it to check how the code is used in other places in the project. Then as a final step you ask it to produce the documentation comment.  With a bunch of context, it is perfectly capable of creating a sensible comment.

There are severe limitations - it does not see linked JIRA tasks for example and Git history. The advantage here is that that human partner does not need to do it themselves, which hopefully speeds up the process.

@Basilevs I think you are talking about something different than in the question. The question is about not maintaining comments and documentation at the time of writing but having them written "on demand" perhaps years later

@RichardTingle you are right, hoping that issue tracking and Git history are available years later is silly. I just thought that temporal and context gap are not worth mentioning (are obvious) and assumed that we are discussing a feasible alternative.

I have never seen either issue tracking or Git history have sufficient detail to include why the author did a weird thing on a particular line, or the specific reasons for a function; usually you only find that stuff out as you are writing. Sure you could massively inflate the history to put that information in. But why? Why not put it in the far more sensible position it is currently put in, in a structured way that is much more easily accessible

@RichardTingle: To add to your point about inflating the commit history to put that information in; that would be susceptible to a git squash command, and likely would become a nightmare once a rebase goes awry. Having the comments on-site of the actual codebase lets people know "Hey - this comment doesn't describe what's actually happening in the code, I should track down whether the comment or the code is correct here.".

In many cases, the most useful comments are those which don't describe how something works, but those that describe what alternatives were considered, and whether they were found to be inferior or might be worth further exploration.  Such information won't be present in code itself, and examination of the code won't be able to create it.
Generative AI is a nice parlor trick, and for some quick graphics tasks like thumbnail generation it may actually be useful, but the results shouldn't be trusted unless vetted.  If one uses results without vetting, generative AI may yield some slight benefits if one doesn't mind the more significant losses when it turns out to be just plain wrong.  If one vets the results sufficiently to avoid consequences for mistakes, the effort spent vetting could have been spent as well simply doing the original task.

I think the fundamental problem here is how many managers think of source code as an instruction manual on both the art of development and on how they do business.
So if they have a piece of code, however pathetically trivial, they follow the logic that there is, within the code, both the information necessary to produce a new developer capable of writing that code or similar code, and an explanation of how their business works (in a rich, meaningful way) and why the code was designed that way in the first place.
Their view on AI is also typically informed by the hype that it is somehow "intelligent" in the way that developers are reckoned to be, and that AI is as intelligent as the most intelligent developers out there.
It is from these ludicrous opinions that they proceed to think that AI can successfully explain a piece of code and answer arbitrary questions about it, in a way that an average developer cannot quickly do for themselves or in a way that eliminates the need for a skilled and familiar developer on their staff.
Now code commentary has only one function. It is to introduce design information, readable by the developer, which would not otherwise be recorded in the code at all (because it is not necessary for computer execution, it is only relevant to the developer engaged in design or re-design).
Sometimes commentary pulls together information that seems to be present latently in the code once you know to look for it, but the problem is that it is spread diffusely and with no visible sign of the connection - the purpose of the commentary is still to introduce new information that is not in the code itself.
Perhaps occasionally, it is to draw the attention of the developer to a specific pitfall which would otherwise get hidden amongst the thickets of code.
So understanding that the purpose of comments is to record things that the code otherwise doesn't record, there is absolutely no reason to think AI will make code commentary redundant, unless your commentary was already unnecessary.
Because an AI, in analysing the code, certainly cannot extract more from it than a skilled developer who is concentrating on reading it. And by waffling about the code, it certainly does not help to highlight pitfalls or important features either, but simply buries them in a different haystack.
Those who study software history will find that there is hype every few years about techniques which are supposedly "intelligent" and will eliminate the need for skilled developer labour. Yet there are more developers than ever before.
The curse of studying history, of course, is to be doomed to stand by and see the same mistakes made over.

"Because an AI, in analysing the code, certainly cannot extract more from it than a skilled developer" That is not clear at all. Maybe it is so now, but it will likely happen that AI exceeds us in code understanding and description. And perhaps everything else. And besides, skilled developers are ultra expensive.

In fact, to give you an example of how bad we are at writing and maintaining code: we need a language like Rust that enforces certain things so that we don't shoot ourselves. And this language is getting more and more attention, e.g. from Linux kernel developers. Aren't Linux kernel developers skilled? If so then why do we suffer over and over again from stack overflow bugs (one of the main reasons to introduce Rust)? My point is that AI tool can exceed human, and is some areas of programming it does this even now.

@freakish, firstly you seem to be speculating now about an "intelligent" technology that simply doesn't exist (even in theory or prototype). I don't see why you think it would be appropriate to be effectively discussing fiction from Star Trek, as if its actually here. And secondly you haven't grasped the point that the code does not contain all the relevant explanatory information. When dealing with legacy code, a significant part of my role can involve meeting other staff (to interrogate them for explanatory information which they possess). (1/3)

Another common outcome of analysing legacy code is writing off portions of code that nobody understands and therefore cannot be adapted to any new purpose because nobody knows what existing purpose it currently fulfils (if any). A lot of legacy code in smaller businesses is nonsense anyway - the product of incoherent thinking in the first place, from staff who threw down the gauntlet and left years ago. (2/3)

Developers of ordinary business applications would not use Rust - you'd use languages like Rust for developing hardware or computer operating systems (in other words, only a small minority of developers in specialist employment). There are a wide array of languages that have no manual memory management and therefore have no risks. (3/3)

Who's now speculating on when and why you would use Rust? Also, we're not discussing a fiction here. Static analysis tools find things in code that developers don't, even when they're skilled. It's a fact. That's the reason they exist to begin with. And another fact is, that if code does not contain all the relevant information, then of course a developer won't be able to deduce that information out of thin air. In other words, that information was given to dev through some other channel. And if you feed that information to AI, then in theory it can do the same job.

@freakish, it's not speculation, it's my view as a professional. Rust is basically a more safe C. Nobody nowadays would use C for an ordinary business records application. Even in the 70s they didn't - they mostly used COBOL. You might use C# today for the client side, but that is memory safe by default, and comes with a whopping standard library and UI framework. And implicitly what I'm saying is that I think most developers are engaged in developing ordinary business records applications. Not global computer technology infrastructure, or high-frequency financial trading.

That's irrelevant. We are not discussing who is doing what and in which language.

@freakish, (reflecting your edited comment...), I accept developers are not perfect, but (as we know) so-called AI is also far from perfect with its lies, nonsense "hallucinations", empty blather, and inexplicable workings. And a great many of the imperfections in developer activity are due to incoherent business policies or excessive design complexity which makes it difficult for an ordinary intellect to analyse the correctness of the correspondence between the code and the intended purposes of management. Youth and inexperience also plays a part, when businesses hire inappropriately.

@Steve you are assuming that developer of a client code reads service code. This is neither true nor should be necessary. Service documentation (including comments) abstracts away implementation details and allows clients to use the service without knowing them. This is an essential detail of modularization. Service documentation is hard to write, so it would be nice if a technical writer analyzed the implementation and derived the abstractions from it.

Yeah, well, I don't think perfection exists in this world. My original comment was about "certainly cannot extract more from it than a skilled developer" claim. I disagree with that, Which doesn't mean that I believe AI is, or every will be, perfect. Btw, layers of abstractions exist for human only. Because of their inability of understand whole (often too big) picture. That is not a limitation for AI. Ultimately AI doesn't need modules, abstractions, patterns, or even programming languages - it can generate raw machine code. Just as a offtopic side note.

Btw, it wasn't me who -1 your answer. I agree with most of it.

@Basilevs, the bottom line is that not all important information about the design of the software, is incorporated into the source code. The source code is a product of intelligent design, not a curriculum in how it's design occurred or what things were taken into account. If I give you a manufactured car engine, you wouldn't seriously think someone could make that from raw ore, or readapt it, just from seeing it? It's the product of billions of pounds of design effort. Or if I give you a novel to read, you don't suddenly become a successful novelist or even a competent script doctor.

@freakish, there may be AI facilities that can detect things which are present but not clear without it being pointed out - like needles in haystacks. My point is that a lot of source code simply doesn't contain the relevant information. There is no analysis of source code that will tell you that a certain rule was put in 4 years ago because there was a recording error and the managing director said to handle the error in a particular way - and the rule can now be removed because there is only 3 years of data kept. That kind of information about the design is simply not present in the code.

@Steve yes. However my point is that the same problem applies to human devs. They won't get that information out of nowhere. You just need more context, that's all. It is in no way a flaw or a problem, or weakness of AI.

@freakish, but my central point is that humans are both the creators and the reservoirs of this information. My argument is not that a human developer can read things out of the code that AI cannot (although this remains true). My argument is that the human developer has sources of information besides the code - the designer of the code has access to the richest possible understanding of the design because it was created in their own heads. And even with legacy code, human developers can interrogate other humans for information. (1/2)

Most people when they imagine an AI, they mean something capable of answering questions with the information it already has, or with access to the codebase. Not an AI that simply bounces every important question back to the lead developer in order to learn, or schedules a series of meetings to interrogate the managing director for the information, or answers truthfully with "the information has been lost from the business". Nor are they going to tolerate a massive new documentation and technical writing effort, and all the extra staff, just to provide something for the AI to ingest. (2/2)

@Steve well, it is a matter of supplying that information to AI. For example it could scan all repositories, servers, wikis, and even mails and chats. That's likely to be enough. Of course it opens a separate question about privacy and security, but let's not dig into this. Although some companies (google) already do that. And for decades now. Either way, it is not impossible, and not even far away from reality in my opinion. On the other hand I think that most people totally overestimate human value.

Not sure that is a management opinion. As a developer I too hold the opinion that a code should explain what it does and why it is like it is - or rather the respective project which might include "non-code" that is stored right next to the code. It should definitely explain the business decisions for why the code is like it is. If you mean with the "art of development" that it teaches non developers to develop, then sure, that is absurd, but then the assumption management thinks that also would need some additional proof...cause I've never encountered that thinking.

@freakish, again though, you're talking about technologies that basically don't exist, and you're assuming that just scanning all extant written materials is sufficient. In reality, lots of things simply never leave the head of the developer who designs the software, or are the product of the developer learning from undocumented practical experiences. And extracting that knowledge in a coherent form would be a challenge in its own right and have an unwelcome cost.

@FrankHopkins, it's desirable for code to be self-explanatory in all respects, but it's not my experience that the vast majority of code actually is. And I've regularly encountered the idea that code should be a curriculum in its own design - after all, you've just expressed that very notion! It's difficult to imagine what "self-explanatory" code is, unless it means code that somehow explains all aspects of why it has been designed in a particular way. I find such explanations require voluminous amounts of writing in natural language - far more lines of explanation than lines of code.

@Steve I mainly find that line could discriminate a bit more. In general, the beginning as an introduction doesn't make it particularly clear how that relates to OP's question. Are you assuming OP is a manager and asks from what you describe as manager view? Otherwise it feels a big weird to bring in managers and their view when OP seems to ask this question "naively" from an independent perspective, i.e. sounds like a valid question any Junior dev might ask themselves when the existing devs insist on comments or the like.

@Steve otherwise: I guess it mostly depends how much context you assume as a given. My standard typically is that someone that gets introduced to the team and thus the general context of what type of projects the team is responsible for - then any well maintained project/repository should be self-explanatory such that a "regular" or "senior" developer can figure out what and why that project is doing in reasonable time with a low WTF-count. I feel (in some reasonable deviation range) that perspective is a pretty normal expectation for a well maintained project from a developer.

All in all, I think the second half has several valid points, to me it's just that the first half as introduction doesn't connect them particularly well with the OP's question / is additional fluff making assumptions about managers and where the question is derived from. So as improvement you might work on that part a bit. Just as feedback.

@FrankHopkins, on my reference to "managers", this was not ill-considered. I believe that the typical developer who has ever been expected to work with a codebase written by anyone other than themselves (i.e. legacy code) without the facility to correspond with the creator (often an ex-employee), which incorporates analysis and design work that took many months or years to execute (and may be imperfect or have now-outdated assumptions), knows that the source code is not self-explanatory about that design work. (1/3)

And in my view, the mendacious hype about the capabilities of AI which now permeates our society for the time being (which the OP echoes but certainly isn't the originator of), is specifically designed by its originators to misrepresent the nature and informational content of source code in a way that appeals to the incorrect presumptions, preconceptions, and appetites of non-technical managers. (2/3)

I have an idea what those presumptions and appetites are, because I've encountered them repeatedly over the years in many work settings - even from those who can passibly write small amounts of code, but whose overriding role and mentality is as emissaries of capitalist management, with their imperative to disempower and diminish the importance of those who actually do the work and possess the real skill and know-how of it. Indeed, this was partly what those who devised the Agile Manifesto were reacting against, and why Fowler now disparages the co-opted "Agile-industrial complex". (3/3)

@FrankHopkins, also on "well-maintained projects", in my view a typical good standard to achieve is that the code is in a condition where one or more of its creators remain in control of it, and can continue to incrementally readapt it with reasonable effort and safety. I don't believe most bespoke business applications achieve a standard where a completely new development team could be applied from a cold start, using only available written artefacts, and with no contact with the original creators, and ever regain a comparable capability to the original developers. (1/3)

I think when developers do get given legacy code cold, they either hesitate to make alterations due to the danger (and thus all but the most imperative maintenance stops), they hack away and cause damage, or (if feasible, which often it isn't) they engage in a lengthy reanalysis of the application and/or the business, as necessary to regenerate the original developer's understanding - basically redoing the original developer's activity and taking a comparable amount of time and effort for it. (2/3)

With only normal resources and timeframes available, I don't believe there is any effective technique that facilitates the ability of a team of fresh developers to inherit legacy code cold and perform like the team which created the code (in terms of their ability to explain the correspondence between the business and the software design, and continue changing the code correctly, and their ability to do it at a useful pace). I don't see how AI as we currently know it, will change that equation. (3/3)

The documentation of a function/method/class/interface should not be what it does, but its contract: what it commits to do, and what it doesn't commit to do, not how it does it. You have the source code for that!
AI can tell you what the function does and how it does it. Only the people who designed it can tell you what they promise it will do.
Remember that:

The implementation may change. What works today in cases not in the contract may not work in the future.
Most functions are quite a bit more complex than checking whether an integer is even, and will most often call other functions, both in the same package and in other ones, as well as system functions. Some of those may in turn vary in what they do (in time, or on different platforms). Do you want a description that tells you "this functions calls this if X and that if Y"? Or do you want it to tell you what the overall result is?


Comments should not explain what the code does. They should explain why the code exists. A.I. will never explain what the original coders intent was. We don’t need A.I. for this. We need coders who know what comments are for. Tell me why you wrote this. Tell me why I should ever call it. How it works is really not the business of comments.
I should be able to refactor this code so that it uses a bit mask to do the same thing without touching a comment. If refactoring breaks the comments then those are bad comments.

Documentation often explains what the code does. The intent is to allow clients to consumer the API without reading the implementation. This is the very idea of INTERFACE - isolation of implementation from clients. Of course, explaining the reasoning is also important when it is not obvious.
How often do you read the source of standard library of your preferred language? What about its documentation?

@Basilevs bad documentation explains what the code does. Good documentation explains what you can expect. What the code does IS the implementation. What I can expect IS the interface. I don't need to know the implementation to consume the API. All I need from the implementation is to be faithful to the API.

I agree that inline comments should not explain how the code works with one exception: if you are required to do something really odd (like instantiate an object that is never used) in order for things to work, there should be a comment so it's clear that it wasn't a mistake.

@JimmyJames yes every good rule has an exception. Arcane kludges could make some discussion of what is happening permissible. But in those cases also explaining WHY?!? becomes even more critical.

@candied_orange Maybe I misunderstand why you mean by 'why' and 'how'.  I guess I generally don't want to see any comments in the body of a method unless there's something really interesting to explain. Comments like that tend to be useless redundancies or wrong. I generally delete them if I am refactoring. Perhaps ironically, gen-AI is contributing to more such comments because that's one way to tell GH copilot to write code. But in that case, they might be actually useful because if the generated code is wrong, you won't know what the intention was.

Yes comments are obsolete. But not because of generative AI. Because you your function is just IsEven and that's enough.
On the question of AI, we should note its not explaining the function. It's searching millions of lines of code for similar functions and their comments and the documentation for the operations. finding the similarities and the generating similar looking text with your variable and function names substituted in.
try
public bool CheckEven(int number)
{
    return (number ++) % 2 != 0;
}


...In other words, the method returns true if number is odd and false
if number is even....

https://deepai.org/chat

In the first paragraph You seem to generalize that comments are obsolete, but your argument is specific to OP's toy example. Please disambiguate if you mean that comments in general are obsolete or if comments for simple self-explanatory functions are obsolete

I mean more generally, but I don't want to get into the "how many comments should you have" argument here. We can just look at the type of comment the OP is talking about and see that its not helpful

There are plenty of bad AIs over there. I think the question implies that a somewhat good specialized tool would be used.

this one is free, so its good for examples. but you can test in others as well if you like and tell me if they give the correct response for my example function

Interesting.  Also interesting is to see how this LMM is sensitive to the names that you use in your code.  I tried a random piece of code, and it was giving me a quite impressive deduction over a very partial piece of code.  I then renamed all variables and functions to use minimal abbreviations in another human language,  and the LMM was incapable of giving any meaning except commenting on the expressions.  (experiment both starting a new anonymous browsing session to avoid any history bias). Of course, for this simple example it still works, yet it gives slightly different explanations.

@Basilevs I mean, to some degree there's better and worse LLM code analysis tools, but there's limitations inherent in the technology, and limitations inherent in what anything can do just given the code (and not other context). An LLM isn't designed in a way that it could genuinely do thorough, logical analysis of code's functionality, no matter how good of an LLM it is.

@RadvylfPrograms are you?

Why not design it like that then? Give it access to JIRA and it will know more than an average contractor.

Is this meant to imply that the LLM's answer is incorrect? Despite the name, CheckEven indeed returns true if and only if number is odd.

@Basilevs No matter what you train it on, all an LLM does is look at a series of words (well, tokens) and predict what word comes next. It's not a matter of what you train it on, there's just inherently only so much critical thinking it can be capable of. Us humans can analyze code more effectively because, while we do have parts of our brains that string together words based on what we said last, we also have parts of our brains for more abstract thinking.

@AlexJones yes, I realised a while back. leaving it in though for the irony. you can confuse it with ++ number though

@RadvylfPrograms you are forgetting that people too are "predicting" next word based on context. Arguably they are much less efficient, because their training effort can't be reused as easily. AI has demonstrated a capability for abstract thinking multiple times. So I'm not sure where are you coming from.

I would like to upvote the second part of this answer, but the "Yes comments are obsolete" statement is too wrong. "Yes the comments in your example are unnecessary" would be much better.

this answer could be improved by providing the result you got from the AI (and argue along it why the output is bad) - as the output might change over time, the link might become dead etc.

Comments on method signatures have been "obsolete" for decades provided the method signature conveys enough information for the human to understand what the method does at a high level. This isn't a new development because of AI or LLMs.
In September 2022, I would have stated that there is no point to add comments to a method signature if the method name, return type, parameter names, and parameter types are already meaningful. Fast-forward to today, and AI chat bots are a household name. My recommendation still stands. Comments in this narrow use case are unnecessary now, and they were unnecessary then. The method signature comments state the obvious. So obvious, in fact, that a machine learning algorithm can predict the most likely string of words that a human would use to describe it, because many humans have written similar code and comments that were used to train the model.
This is not a criticism of large language models. Instead, it is good to be mindful of the limitations of this technology. LLMs are a tool like any other. You need to understand how to use them for it to be effective. Rather than say "Boo AI! Yay humans!", here are some guidelines for determining when to offload this to an LLM:

If the method signature is obvious at first glance to a human, it doesn't need comments, nor does the human need AI to explain anything. To be honest, this is old advice that predates LLMs by many, many years. I believe your code example falls into this category.

If an LLM gives an uncommented method a good summary, then don't invest time in adding comments. This assumes other developers have access to this kind of tool. Beware that different LLMs can give different output. Do each of the developers working on this codebase have access to the same LLM? If not, consider commenting the method anyways.

When a LLM cannot accurately describe the method, and neither can a human, then the human better write some comments to explain this to everyone. None of us know what the &$#@ this code is doing — carbon-based or silicon-based intelligence.

Once the human has written good comments, it would be nice to incorporate this information into the corpus of data used to train the LLM so it has a better chance of summarizing similar-looking code in the future.


And finally, remember that the limitations of LLMs are evolving quickly. Better training data or algorithms can change the decision to offload some of this cognitive work to artificial intelligence.


Code comments are a tool, just like IDEs, and large language models. The onus is on the human to understand the use cases and limitations of each tool before using it. I think declaring code comments obsolete is too broad to properly capture the nuance of communication between engineers. More likely, current LLMs will augment our existing tools, rather than replacing them. Comments are not obsolete, but the use cases for comments might change because of the introduction of a new tool.

"If the method signature is obvious at first glance to a human, it doesn't need comments, nor does the human need AI to explain anything" Just because new developers may look at this answer, I'd like to suggest a slight departure from this.  If one does not have the experience nor discipline to really determine if a signature is obvious, it may be wise to put the comments on the signature anyways.  In my personal experience, I've seen units and frames dropped because a developer momentarily forgot that they weren't obvious.

I think that is a fair critique. Experience matters. I will try to update my answer later without falling into a black hole on this one. My counter-argument would be that inexperienced developers should either spend time analyzing code or summarize it with an LLM until they become more comfortable. I was hoping to convey that this decision exists on a spectrum, rather than a black-and-white canvas.

@GregBurghardt, if novice developers never read code and spend all their time having AI summarise it in natural language, then I struggle to understand how they will ever develop the skills necessary to read the code! One of the key competencies of a developer is learning to be slavishly precise with details (since the computer will perform no further intelligent interpretation of its instructions) - in my experience, the absence of this ability is one of the characteristics of those who want to code but cannot! So I agree with you that code should not be tailored to complete novices.

"Do each of the developers working on this codebase have access to the same LLM?" Tools change but code lives for years. Even if every dev has access to the same LLM right now will that hold four years from now on?

There are already plenty answers that address the core issue of whether an AI can generate a comment well enough without further supervision and whether the "reader-side" generation strategy rather than an "author-side" supervised variant to use AI's to generate comments is a good one.
However, there are also a few additional indirect limitations to where this approach can work based on outside requirements and economic factors.
For many projects applying an AI to the source code is simply not an option. Because:

It is or will be expensive (using the most powerful AI model); it currently is expensive for the AI model providers, they just hope for later return of investment and it is questionable whether AI tailored to software generation will be able to finance itself with advertisement like search engines
It cannot easily be self hosted (simple models yes, the really powerful ones are proprietary along with some of the tooling)
Code might need to be editable offline: Not every place has internet connection, not every system is connected to the internet and AI systems are typically web based; even if just a temporary issue, it slows down the development flow if a comment/functionality description is not available when you need it
If the model is not hosted by the company, they might - e.g. for security or privacy reasons - not want to apply the AI to all their data including their issue tracking systems as both the actual code as well as the issues might be very important strategic assets, the company might want to protect as best as it can; external service providers, potentially even hosted in foreign countries are not exactly trustworthy enough for many companies/projects; Tickets could also have customer data that should not leave the company premises.
Many accessible AI models do not learn in general from your data, they just include it in a particular query evaluation. The ones that keep learning are more prone to being misled, more expensive and would either mix your data with external data (if an external service) or be even more expensive to run ^^

Perhaps AI will become massively cheaper to run and everyone has it running locally on their machine. That would alleviate most of the external factors mentioned here, but currently that is not in sight. For example, this article from Business insiders stipulates that 1) Tech companies plan on spending over $1 trillion on artificial intelligence. 2) The return on investment may take a long time and be disappointing 3) some experts said AI might not perform well enough to justify its exorbitant cost
And on the practical side, AI surely might change the way we program, but either it gets so good it can program on its own or it needs human supervision - which then also holds for writing comments - and will remain a tool in writing code and comments by humans for humans.

Maybe, soon an AI will write your comments. And yet another AI will read the generated comments to digest it for someone else.  I bet that if the generated comments are as fluffy as in your example,  the latter will become increasingly popular.
Meanwhile, we all know since clean code that comments are not supposed to waste our time for obvious explanations (here, 11 lines of blabla to explain 1 line of code). Focus should be on what's not so easy to grasp in the code, and in that case, comments are an investment for the future with little overhead.  At least you're sure that the vital minimum is there.

It is not a bad idea, if your code is self-explanatory.
Comments are a nice tool to express concepts that have meanings in a higher level of abstraction respect the one of source code. Pointless if they just rephrase what code already "say".
But... AI support is welcomed when the coder still has to be trained and those inferences that are obvious for the seasoned developer, would require efforts for her (the apprentice) to be done (at the cost of disturbing her flow).
Instead: even the apprentice can benefit from reading about things (in the comments) that ... well: she does not fully understand, but she will do, one day.
A common behavior is limiting the context (meaning, subject) of what can/should be said in comments. Usually we talk about the software itself, not about the design, not about the method with which we choose one design instead another one.
This behavior is common when/where the same source code must be shared among different developers and other roles. In this case, the source is not a good place in which to talk about design methods.
When the source is handled by just one developer things change and comments become also a reasoning (even thought informal) tool.
It's not said that comments have to express just informal expressions. They can be also formal.
